# Why source codes aren't commented

Tags: conventions

Every programming course tell us that we shoul use as much comments as possible to make things clear which makes sense. Because you will forget what you did if you read it in the future.

How come professional source codes contain virtually no comments? wouldn't it make it more readable?

Example (istream) from C++:

```
  template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
    class basic_istream : virtual public basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>
    {
    public:
      // Types (inherited from basic_ios (27.4.4)):
      typedef _CharT                    char_type;
      typedef typename _Traits::int_type        int_type;
      typedef typename _Traits::pos_type        pos_type;
      typedef typename _Traits::off_type        off_type;
      typedef _Traits                   traits_type;

      // Non-standard Types:
      typedef basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>      __streambuf_type;
      typedef basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>        __ios_type;
      typedef basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>        __istream_type;
      typedef num_get<_CharT, istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits> >
                            __num_get_type;
      typedef ctype<_CharT>                 __ctype_type;

    protected:
      // Data Members:
      /**
       *  The number of characters extracted in the previous unformatted
       *  function; see gcount().
      */
      streamsize        _M_gcount;

    public:
      /**
       *  @brief  Base constructor.
       *
       *  This ctor is almost never called by the user directly, rather from
       *  derived classes' initialization lists, which pass a pointer to
       *  their own stream buffer.
      */
      explicit
      basic_istream(__streambuf_type* __sb)
      : _M_gcount(streamsize(0))
      { this->init(__sb); }
```

The question is about actual policies software companies have concerning comments.

Comment: A typical policy for code to be submitted to a client is that a method or type should be documented at its start but internally there should be very few or no comments. Well written code is its own documentation.

Comment: Matt’s answer is why developers think their code doesn’t need comments. Well written code is only “enough” in simple situations. Comments like “this is a cat” aren’t helpful, but explaining certain decisions or summarizing what a given code block does can be lifesavers for whoever is maintaining your code (could be you in six months’ time). If it takes me 30 seconds to understand your code by reading it, save me time and give me a 4 second comment.

Comment: So basically companies that have “no comment” policies are, I would argue, doing things badly. I encourage every team I work with to write intelligent comments, and they are (mostly) grateful by the end of it.

Comment: It's more typical to have separate documentation of code, and have the comments stripped out, for cleanliness/file size reduction. In other words, you work on a codebase, with comments, and then whenever there is a deployment or delivery to production/a client, strip out the comments and external parties/clients rely on documentation that is available separately.

Comment: Useful comments tend to add to what the code already says, rather than restating it; the "why", rather than "what" or "how" (the source control system keeps track of the "who" and "when")

Comment: Note that the code you posted does have comments; they (a) explain things that aren't clear from the code, and (b) organise it into sections

Answer (score 1):

The reason?

Many software developers are already proficient in a certain language, in this case it is C++. While comments *do make learning easier* for beginners wanting to learn what code means, they become less and less necessary as the programmer moves up in knowledge. For example, the Python code might need some comments to explain it to a beginner:

```py
class House:
    def __init__(self, rooms, people):
        self.rooms = rooms
        self.people = people
myHome = House(3, 5)
print(myHome.rooms)
```

But advanced programmers might immediately know that it is a script that creates an object.

If you are...

- talking about proprietary companies, you're right. Closed-source programs are not meant to be modified, rather, to be distributed as binaries. Companies might do this to obfuscate the code so no one knows what it means. There might only be one comment, and it might only be at the top of the file, stating the copyright.
- Open-source developers are different. The code can, most of the time, be edited and distributed freely. Here, there might be comments.

Of course, there's the meme of instructors telling students to comment every ***single*** line of code:

```js
function // function keyword
promptValue() // function name
{ // brace
  var // assign
  x // variable name
  = // equals sign
      prompt("foo"); // prompt function
  alert(x); // alert it out
  return // return keyword
  0; // All OK
} // closing brace
promptValue // function name
(); // no arguments
```

Not only is this an eyesore to read, it's harder to understand. If you name variables and functions with descriptive names, then you can get rid of many comments.

A common misconception is: `The more comments, the better.` Actually, flooding code with comments will only make the code harder to read. If a lot of code needs comments, check that all the names are descriptive.

Another thing to note that people said in the comments is that a lot of software have separate documentation. You can explain the code here.

So some code isn't commented because it's self-explanatory, and some aren't commented because it's a secret.

Comment: But isn't the motivation of doing this one way rather that another also relevant? Comments may not only say what the code does but also why does it do it in this specific way.

Comment: `If the code is really clear, like a print() statement, there's no need for a comment. You can see from the code in the question that it defines a class.`